# How to create tables in the markLogic by using sql

Tags: sql, marklogic, nosql

Good morning all,

How to create employees table in the marklogic by using sql or javascript?

Thanks in advance,
Naveen

Answer (score 5):

You do not create tables in MarkLogic. You insert individual structured documents (XML/JSON) where each document is as close as you would get to the idea of a table row in a relational database.

For use of SQL to query these documents, MarkLogic allows you to create views. These are similiar to views in SQL and expose specific elements/attributes/properties of your documents.

I think you need to read the section on SQL in MarkLogic as a starting point and then come back with more specific questions if you get stuck.  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/intro

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic is schema agnostic, you can achieve a structure thru a Schema database to enforce document structure. Just create your XSD file and your document can be validated against that.

Check this link for more information:
https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2007-04-schema

Answer (score 0):

Since MarkLogic is schema-agnostic database, you can restrict the element/attribute or define the XML structure through XSD.
However if you want to create tables using SQL, you actually have to create views.
Please check more on `https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/intro`.

N.B : If you are creating views, make sure range-index is created for all the elements or attributes that you wish to use.